# Combine variable with loop

Tags: javascript

I need to combine 2 variable names, but it must be in a for loop. Also I need to get the variable from a php file to know how long the loop must be.

I have while loop in php file which count how many objects I have and make "$k++" for every object. After while loop I have variable what store count of objects $galak=$k-1 ... I need to make javascript something like:

```
document.getElementById("galak");
var i;
for (i = 1; i < galak; i++) {
    var decimalMask.i = new InputMask(JST_MASK_DECIMAL, "rdcena".i);
}
```

After loop "for" there must be decimalMask1,decimalMask2,decimalMask3 etc. and rdcena1,rdcena2,rdcena3 etc.

So question is how to add variable "i" value to other variables decimalMask and rdcena?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate them. Replace `.` with `+`. `+` is the concatenation operator in javascript. And make `decimalMask` an array.

```
decimalMask[i] = new InputMask(JST_MASK_DECIMAL, "rdcena" + i);
```

Then it can be accessed as `decimalMask[1]` or `decimalMask[2]`...

Comment: Hmm.. it would be good to make array and store 'new InputMask(JST_MASK_DECIMAL, "rdcena" + i)' there. Can you show how to make string array decimalMask and then use 'var decimalMask[i] =' ?

Comment: Just define it - `var decimalMask = []`

Comment: Now all work fine except "document.getElementById("galak");".. seems like it don't read value stored in it.. mby you could make solution? because  loop "for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) " works good, but for (i = 1; i < galak; i++)  don't work at all..